# IPhone Facebook Api Friends.getLists returns nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

In my application I try to get list of friends using Facebook Api method `Friends.getLists`. 
I have to use this Api since I use another methods from this Api in my App and they works fine. So I cannot use others methods. This code returns just nothing:

```
[[FBRequest requestWithSession: _facebookSession delegate: self] call: @"facebook.Friends.getLists" params: nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `facebook.friends.get` instead, and then `facebook.users.getInfo` to get name of each user.